# Facebook SDK 5 - reading feeds of a page

Tags: php, facebook, drupal

I am trying to read the posts of a facebook page, using the actual Facebook SDK 5 for PHP. I have created a facebook app, downloaded and "required" the SDK successfully, but I cannot get the request to run, since it always throws a `Invalid OAuth access token signature` exception.

The code I have so far:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $appid,
    'app_secret' => $secret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);

$accesstoken = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
    .   "client_id=" . $appid
    .   "&client_secret=" . $secret
    .   "&grant_type=client_credentials" );


//following lines are something I just tried, there have been multiple
//Variantions, none ever worked

$cilent = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

$accessToken = $cilent->getLongLivedAccessToken($accesstoken);
```

All in all my main issues are:

1. how to get a valid access token? Since I just want to read public data (feeds of a page), I do not need some special permissons and I am quite confused which on Type of access token I need.
2. Are there any settings within the facebook app I need to make, or make sure, to get this up and running?

I have googled the web for examples, but I could find examples either using older SDKs (if used at all), or showing how to post data.

I do not have too much experience with that topic and I would appreciate some explanation, or a piece of example.

**[UPDATE]**

I could manage to get the feeds, some dive through the source was needed.

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'xxx',
  'app_secret' => 'xxx',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
]);

$req = $fb->get(
  '/<page-id>/feed?fields=full_picture,message,name,picture,story,posts&limit=20',
  $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken());
```

In case of success everything one is looking for is included in `$res`. For sake of simplicity I removed the error handling.

Because everything is desinged to read public data, there is no need for any access-token huzzle, however, retrieving user Data, posting or something else, is not possible with this solution.

Cheers!